# Not able to install Saltcorn in Windows 10

Tags: npm, vips

I tried to install saltcorn using this wiki page. https://wiki.saltcorn.com/view/ShowPage/install-on-windows-10
It is failing due to vips error

npm 8.1.0
node 16.13.0

```
C:\Users\varsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@saltcorn\cli\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
npm ERR!   nothing.c
npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc
npm ERR!   nothing.vcxproj -> C:\Users\varsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@saltcorn\cli\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\\nothing.lib
npm ERR!   VError.cpp
npm ERR! C:\Users\varsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@saltcorn\cli\node_modules\sharp\src\libvips\cplusplus\VError.cpp(33,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vips/intl.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\varsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@saltcorn\cli\node_modules\sharp\build\libvips-cpp.vcxproj]
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.32002.261) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
```

Answer (score 0):

Your node is too recent, try downgrading to node 15. See:

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install

Background: sharp ships binaries for most platforms, but not yet node16 (as of the time of writing). If it does not have precompiled binaries available, sharp will try to build them for you on your machine using node-gyp. Sadly, especially on windows, this is extremely fragile and can break in 1000s of bizarre ways.

You can spend many hours trying to fix it, or (much more sensibly) you can switch to a supported version of node.